# DataTables how to change the height and fonts on the bottom and top bar?

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

Datatable version: 1.10.12

I have a DataTable and i want to change the height and fonts displayed in the top and bottom bar, I tried many things in CSS, used the element inspect in firefox to apply various settings to .datatables class, but it just wont do anything. I want to change this:

[image]

it is too big (in height) for me.... I also want to change the heights of the rows to only be as high as the letters inside them, so that i can have more data on screen.

how can i do this? Also is it possible to move all the info from footer like (showing blah blah.. and page buttons, prev/next button etc.) to header itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be nice to see what you have tried, but I believe you forget that you are using [**jquery UI**](https://datatables.net/manual/styling/jqueryui) styling. Target `.ui-button` and `.ui-toolbar` in CSS along with the standard `.dataTables_wrapper` CSS classes :

```css
/* change font in top and bottom */
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter,
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length,
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info,
.dataTables_wrapper .ui-button {
  color: red;
  font-family: 'courier'
}

/* change "height" caused by exaggerated padding */
.dataTables_wrapper .ui-toolbar {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/rqm49duz/**

Comment: thank you. I accepted and up-voted this ans - as it correctly addresses the problem. but i am still looking for slim rows. I tried the same with rows, but it did not work:     .dataTables_wrapper tr {
  padding: 0px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must use `!important` for CSS code.
for second question:
You can use `dom` option for this. For example:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "dom": '<"wrapper"flipt>'
} );
```

[Read more...](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)